# Why the stored procedure is taking more than 50 seconds to retrive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have this procedure and it takes 50 seconds to fetch records.

```
Declare 
        @Emp int
        Set @Emp= 0

    SELECT DISTINCT tp.ProjectNo+' | '+tp.ProjectName as ProjectNo,   
                    tp.ProjectID as ID, 
                    ISNULL(sp.ClientID,0) ClientID,
                    ISNULL(tc.ClientName, '') ClientName
    FROM tp 
            Inner Join sp ON tp.ProjectID = sp.ProjectID
            Inner Join TC ON sp.clientid = tc.ClientID
            Inner Join tpl ON tpl.ProjectNo = tp.ProjectNo
    WHERE   tpl.EmployeeNo = case when @Emp = 0 then tpl.EmpNo else @Emp end
```

Only `tpl` table has 25000 records otherwise other tables has less than 1000 records.

`Tpl` fragmentation is 30%.

How do I speed it up?

It takes time at case statement. How to improve?

Comment: Can you share an execution plan? What about the table structures and indexes? I would also urge you to format your queries and be consistent. You have different syntax options for aliases and your joins aren't consistent with formatting. Not really sure what you mean Tpl fragmentation is 30%. Is that the index fragmentation? Regardless the answer that means that 1 in 3 rows is affected by your fragmentation...fix that.

Comment: Are there any indexes defined for these tables? What is the data types for ProjectNo?

Comment: In addition to other thoughts, why do you have `distinct`? This is usually a sign of applying a band-aid to a gaping wound of a bad join...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate @Emp using an `IF` statement before entering the select.  Maybe you will need to run 2 queries, but both should complete faster than the 1 with case in where.

Comment: Much appreciated. Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

For 25,000 records, SQL shouldn't be breaking a sweat, even with that CASE statement in the WHERE clause. Do you have an index on each of the JOIN predicates? I.e.:

```
[tp].[ProjectID]
[tp].[ProjectNo]

[sp].[ProjectID]
[sp].[clientid]

[tc].[ClientID]

[tpl].[ProjectNo]
```